# R foreach sub-select is slow

Tags: r, foreach

I'm trying to run an lm against a number of data-sets that are currently stacked in columns like:

```
Counter Tag  Value
4       tag_1 8
3       tag_1 1
4       tag_2 4
3       tag_2 82
5       tag_2 5
4       tag_3 6
3       tag_3 2
```

I have another table of the same format. For each tag in that table I want to run an lm and extract the p-value from it. As there is a large number of tags in each I want to run the lm's in parallel & have tried the following:

```
# Setup Parallel Clusters
cl <- makeCluster(num_cpus, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

p_mat_hold <- foreach(i:length(it), .combine=rbind) %dopar%
{

# Get values for tag i
sub_ind_df <- ind_df[which(ind_df$tag_name==ind_tags[i,1]),]

# Merge for modelling
df <- merge(sub_ind_df,sub_dep_df,by="counter")

# Fit lm & extract p-value
fit <- lm(median_value.y ~ median_value.x,data=df, na.action=na.omit)

# Extract p-value
fit_sum <- data.frame(coef(summary(fit)))
pv <- fit_sum[2,4]


}
stopCluster(cl)
```

Note: The main reason I want to do it in parallel is because one table has ~500 tags & the other ~20000, meaning approximately ~10000000 lm's are required.

If I run the contents of the foreach loop one by one outside of the loop they run fine (& fast). If I wrap them in a for loop things are fine, it's only in the foreach loop that things stop running. I tried each line by itself in the foreach & the issue seems to be selecting a tag (in particular the which command in below):

```
    sub_ind_df <- ind_df[which(ind_df$tag_name==ind_tags[i,1]),]
```

I should note that no errors are produced. The problem is the foreach loop runs VERY slow with the above command, which itself runs quite quickly outside of the loop.

Any suggestions? I've tried various options of selecting all to no avail. Some other attempts:

```
ind_tags[i,1] %in% ind_df$tag_name
sqldf(paste0("select * from ind_df where tag_name='",ind_tags[i,1],"'",drv="SQLite")
```

Edit: Some dummy data replicating the original dataset.

```
table_1 <- data.table(counter=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
        tag_name=c('tag_1','tag_1','tag_1','tag_2','tag_2','tag_2','tag_2'),
        value=c(6,3,1,6,3,24,4))

table_2 <- data.table(counter=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4),
          tag_name=c('tag_3','tag_3','tag_3','tag_4','tag_4','tag_4','tag_4'),
           value=c(5,6,23,1,6,3,1))
```

Comment: You could use [fastLm](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RcppArmadillo/docs/fastLm) or [fastLm](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RcppEigen/docs/fastLm). The speed-up should be much better than anything you can achieve with parallelization.

Comment: But, of course, that you are trying to create millions of p-values with this seems dubious.

Comment: And the preparation of `df` could be made more efficient with package data.table or dplyr.

Comment: I tested fastLM vs lm (base) & there wasn't a noticeable speed difference. In fact depending on the data put in, it was slower.

Comment: Thanks heaps for introducing me to the world of data.table over data.frame! It's incredibly fast.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. Anyway, my point remains that there is a big potential for optimizing your code. But without a reproducible example I can't try it.